# Deserialize error response without object mapper in WebClient onErrorResume

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I wonder if there is a better way to get error response in WebClient in a way that does not involve using additional `ObjectMapper` when calling `onErrorResume`?

In my WebClient:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.BadRequest

// ...

.onErrorResume(BadRequest::class.java, badRequestToMyDto())
```

```kotlin
    private fun badRequestToMyDto(): (BadRequest) -> Mono<out MyDto> =
        { it: BadRequest ->
            val error = objectMapper.readValue<ErrorResponseDto>(it.responseBodyAsByteArray)
            // ...
}
```

There is a method `.bodyToMono` so I wonder if there is something similar that can be used in `onErrorResume`.

Comment: Consider using `exchangeToMono`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `retrieve()` in combination with `onStatus` to get access the client response when it is an "error". You can then invoke `bodyToMono` on it to unmarshall the response to a java object. Depending on the content type of the response body, spring will use the correct decoder. For examaple, if the body is json, it will use an `ObjectMapper` for unmarshalling.

```java
WebClient.builder().build()
                .get()
                .uri("localhost:8080")
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse ->
                        clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyErrorResponse.class)
                                .flatMap(body -> {
                                    // logic
                                })
                )
```

Comment: and you can propagate deserialized response as mono?